# Perspective projection bug (not understanding theory)

Tags: graphics, perspective, depth-buffer

I'm implementing my own renderer based on rasterization and depth buffering with the CPU. As you can see in the next image it **works**!

[image: Sample image of a rendered box of dimensions 1000x1000x10]

However, there's something **terribly wrong**! Even that the box looks like a cube, its dimensions are 1000x1000x10. The "foreshortening" is too high. If I change the dimensions to 1000x1000x1000, the box goes to the infinite:

[image: Sample image of a rendered box of dimensions 1000x1000x1000]

This happens because there's something that I'm missing in the perspective projection. When I do the perspective projection (3D world to 2D screen) I apply the view transform (place the coordinate system at the camera position and with proper orientation). To simplify things, my camera has the same orientation as the world, the only thing that it changes is the position, is at (0, 0, -1):

```
  const Point3D point_camera = {
     point_world.x * m_left.x + point_world.y * m_up.x + point_world.z * m_forward.x - m_position.x,
     point_world.x * m_left.y + point_world.y * m_up.y + point_world.z * m_forward.y - m_position.y,
     point_world.x * m_left.z + point_world.y * m_up.z + point_world.z * m_forward.z - m_position.z
  };
```

And then I apply the perspective division dividing each component of the 3D world point by its Z:

```
  const Point2D point_projected = {
     (point_camera.x * m_near * m_zoom) / point_camera.z,
     (point_camera.y * m_near * m_zoom) / point_camera.z
  };
```

I feel like I should be multiplying the Z by some kind of factor...but I can't figure it out. Maybe the `w` has something to do with this? If someone could help me or forward me to a good explanation of the theory behind the perspective projection I will be very grateful.

All the code is on my [github](https://github.com/mtrebi/Rasterizer). The relevant classes are `PerspectiveCamera` and `ForwardRasterizer`

Comment: Try changing the member of your Camera class m_far to something larger, maybe 2000 rather than 50. Your box of 1000^3 is way outside this range. Normally if you were using openGL or another graphics API such distant geometry would be clipped into the the canonical view volume, so you wouldn't get such a weird effect.

Comment: In my local code for the previous images m_far was set to 5000 but nice suggestion

Comment: Ah I thought I may have been on to something :)
In that case, take a look at this githhub repo. https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h It's a single header file that implements a bunch of commonly used matrix, quaternion and vector ops. I use it pretty much exclusively for all my projects. The author has a solid perspective projection implementation in there. Maybe check yourself against what he's doing.

Comment: He uses a formula that normalizes the z in the range [-1, 1] to do the perspective division. I've included this formula in my code but I'm still not able to see if it works or not because I've found a bug that I must fix first.

Comment: Well, now that I've fixed everything, its working better but I still don't understand why. Instead of diving by `point_camera.z` in the perspective divide, I'm dividing by `((m_far + m_near) / (m_far - m_near)) + 
                      (1 / depth) * ((2 * m_near*m_far) / (m_far - m_near))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to transform a 3 dimensional vector or point using a 4x4 matrix, as you probably already know, you need to augment it with another component (frequently called **w**). For the sake of proper transformation **w** is often chosen to be 1 Such that **(x, y, z)** becomes **(x, y, z, 1)**.

Let's assume that your point has already been transformed into view space, so that it's 'in front' of the camera. The next, and last, transformation that you want to perform is the actual projection. If you multiply the vector against [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/building-basic-perspective-projection-matrix) matrix (which is a bit different from Datenwolfs) you will get a resulting column vector that looks similar to this

[image: Vector multiplication against perspective matrix]

I should mention, in this vector I left out the scaling of **x** and **z** for the aspect ratio  just to make things a little more clear.

You can see that the third element in the vector is effectively normalizing **z** as you mentioned. Lets assume **w** is still 1, **f** which is our far plane is 100, and **n** our near plane is 10. With this assumption, the third element becomes.

[image]

If you plug in a few different numbers for **z** that are in the range [10, 100] then you will see that this is indeed just normalizing the **z**.

The magic of projection happens in an unseen step, a division by of **x'**, **y'**, **z'** by **w'** which applies the actual perpective effect to **x'** and **y'** in screen space, but also renormalizes your **z'** such that it's value looks something like this as the point moves away from the viewer.
[image]

As a side note, the shape of the graph is intentional. It's to take advantage of the precision limitations of the depth buffer, but that's a whole other discussion.

The last thing I would like to make note of is the negative value of **w'** in the column vector. You might be thinking to yourself, "Why on earth would they do that? Wouldn't that flip everything vertically and horizontally?" And you are right, that's exactly what it does. The reason for that is something I've already mentioned a few times. The canonical view volume, which for OpenGL has screen space mappings that look like this.

[image]

Unlike other screen coordinate systems, the origin is in the dead center of the screen. No matter the screen's dimensions. In addition to that quirk, the most positive coordinate is in the upper right of the screen, rather than the lower right. Consequentially, in many cases your projected coordinates must then be flipped, hence the **-z** as the value for **w'**.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: This answer helped me to find the solution but I'd like to make a few notes. First, I think the first equation that you present is not correct because there's an extra minus sign in the first element. It should be `(z*f)/ (f-n) - w * ((f*n)/(f-n))` Secondly, when you substitute the values of the first equation you are missing some parameters. The equation should be `100z/90 - 1000/90`. Said that, the answer was really helpful.

Comment: @mtrebi, good catch. I partially simplified those fractions, and in turn totally screwed it up haha. In regards to the minus sign. That actually should be there, it's negating that whole term. Remember that it's later being divided by -z which will bring it back into the positive realm.